# Can I use Vitamio Android Library Demo version in my app for uploading Google Play store?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, android-video-player, vitamio

I am using Vitamio Android Library Demo version in one of my Video Player. But my app was rejected by Google for using "Third Party Content". Then I changed the seekbar,hanlder and everything so that it looks unique. But Google rejected again for the same reason! Why ? My other contents are ok but this time I won't realize that what types of Third party content I used! Can't we use Vitamio Android library for making app ?

Comment: I don't think Vitamio is the problem here. However, Demo version might be. Where are you getting the content from that you're playing? Are you authorized to use that content? As a side note, you should read up on [these](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/4407611) policies to acquaint yourself to the Play Store policies. But best is to [Contact](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/publishing?extra.IssueType=submitting&hl=en&ec=publish&cfsi=publish_cf&cfnti=escalationflow.email&cft=3&rd=1) Play Store and ask them for an explanation.

Comment: Most of the times these details are usually sent along in an email. If you haven't received them, best resolution is to contact support and ask them for details.